# Problems printing from map<string, struct> in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, printing, iterator

I'm learnig C++. Here is my problem: I'm trying to read data from a text file and save it to a map<string, struct> and then have it print out all the keys from the map preferably in alphabetical order. The data has 2 strigns and a float. I can't get this to print even after having tried many different solutions.
Heres what I've got so far:

**Here is my struct:**

```
struct category
{
   std::string tram_stop;
   float dist;
};

using Tram = std::map<std::string, std::vector<category>>;
```

**Here is where I try to save the data to the map.**

```
void store(Tram& tram, std::vector<std::string>& tram_data)
{
  if (tram.find (tram_data.at (0)) == tram.end ())
  {
     tram[tram_data.at (0)] = {};
  }
  else
  {
     tram.at (tram_data.at (0)).push_back (category {tram_data.at (1), std::stof(tram_data.at(2))});
  }
}
```

**And here is main().**

```
int main()
{
    Tram tram;
    print_rasse();

    // Ask input filename.
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Give a name for input file: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    // Read input file.
    std::ifstream file_in;
    file_in.open (filename);
    if (!file_in.is_open ())
    {
        std::cout << INVALID_FILE <<  std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> tram_data;
    if (file_in.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while( std::getline(file_in,line) )
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);

            std::string tram_line, tram_stop, distance;
            std::getline(ss,tram_line,';');  //std::cout<< ""<<tram_line <<" ";
            std::getline(ss,tram_stop,';'); //std::cout<<" "<<tram_stop<<" ";
            std::getline(ss,distance); //std::cout<<" "<<distance<< " ";

            if (tram_line != "" && tram_stop != "")
            {
                tram_data.push_back (tram_line);
                tram_data.push_back (tram_stop);
                tram_data.push_back (distance);
                //std::cout << tram_line << " " << distance << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << INVALID_FORMAT << std::endl;
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
    }
    file_in.close ();

    store(tram, tram_data);

}
```

**This is the part I think doesn't work. Tried different iterators too.**

```
if (upper_com == "LINES")
{
   std::cout << "All tramlines in alphabetical order:" << std::endl;
   for (auto& item : tram)
   {
     std::cout << item.first << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `Tram`? Your `store` function seems to be overly complex, and handles the first thing stored for a given striing differently from subsequent stores.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this from my post :using Tram = std::map<std::string, std::vector<category>>;
Tram is the map where I'm trying to save the data.

Comment: Please add an exaple input file and a a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry. Newbie. Here's an example of the file:                                        West;Pyynikintori;0
West;Tuulensuu;0.5

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `store` will create a vector for the first item added for a particular `tram_data[0]` value, but will not add anything to the vector. This results in losing that first item, and can result in no output because of the empty vectors.

That function can be simplified:

```cpp
void store(Tram& tram, std::vector<std::string>& tram_data)
{
  if (tram_data.size() < 3) throw std::out_of_range();
  tram[tram_data[0]].emplace_back(tram_data[1], std::stof(tram_data[2]));
}
```

You don't need to use `at` with `tram` because you want to create the entry if it doesn't exist. `at` with `tram_data` will result in an exception being thrown if there are fewer than three elements in `tram_data`, so that check has been moved outside all the accesses to the vector.